# Clock Timer is showing wrong time JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on timer when user clock in the timer starts. It is working fine until it reaches the 60 minutes figure and it keeps on going doesn't added hour. Here is my code

```
  export enum HMS{
  hours=3600,
  MinSec=60,
}

 transform(value: number = 3600): any {
// here values is in minutes
    const hours: number = Math.floor(value / HMS.hours)
    const minutes: number = Math.floor(value / HMS.MinSec);
    const seconds: number = (value - minutes * HMS.MinSec);
    return ((hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds)
  }
```

Below is the image display time. It shows like this.

[image]

Comment: ... or `value` as passed to the function

Comment: Here is the real HMS and value I am passing

Comment: 3660 / 60 is 61. You need the modulus operator: `Math.floor(value / HMS.MinSec) % 60`

Comment: Start with seconds first and use the `%` operator to get remainder after division. i.e. `61 % 60 => 1`. Then subtract the seconds value and repeat for minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need a Modulo in there:

```
export enum HMS{
      hours=3600,
      MinSec=60,
    }
    
transform(value: number = 3600): any {
    // here values is in minutes
    const hours: number = Math.floor(value / HMS.hours)
    const minutes: number = Math.floor(value / HMS.MinSec % 60);
    const seconds: number = Math.floor(value % 60);
    return ((hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds)
}
```